# Как исправить ошибку DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN?

Tags: хостинг, dns, домен

Клиенты иногда жалуются, что периодически не могут получить доступ к сайту. Возникает ошибка, как на скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема не постоянно. Сайту уже больше месяца, т.е. все DNS-кэшы должны были уже обновиться. Проблема скорее всего в настройках DNS-записей на хостинге или регистраторе, но где именно? Куда копать?

PS: скриншоты настроек DNS могу предоставить.

Answer (score 1):

у вас некорректно описано доменное имя.

вот список зарегистированных для обслуживания вашего доменного имени серверов имён:

```
$ whois ваш-домен | grep -i ^name
Name Server: ns1.timeweb.ru 
Name Server: ns2.timeweb.ru 
Name Server: ns3.timeweb.org 
Name Server: ns4.timeweb.org 
Name Server: dns1.yandex.net 
Name Server: dns2.yandex.net
```

первая некорректность — разные сервера показывают разные списки серверов имён:

```
$ for s in dns{1,2}.yandex.net ns{1,2}.timeweb.ru ns{3,4}.timeweb.org; do echo "опрашиваем: $s"; dig +short @$s ns ваш-домен; done
опрашиваем: dns1.yandex.net
dns2.yandex.net.
dns1.yandex.net.
опрашиваем: dns2.yandex.net
dns1.yandex.net.
dns2.yandex.net.
опрашиваем: ns1.timeweb.ru
ns3.timeweb.org.
ns4.timeweb.org.
ns2.timeweb.ru.
ns1.timeweb.ru.
опрашиваем: ns2.timeweb.ru
ns3.timeweb.org.
ns4.timeweb.org.
ns2.timeweb.ru.
ns1.timeweb.ru.
опрашиваем: ns3.timeweb.org
ns3.timeweb.org.
ns4.timeweb.org.
ns2.timeweb.ru.
ns1.timeweb.ru.
опрашиваем: ns4.timeweb.org
ns3.timeweb.org.
ns4.timeweb.org.
ns2.timeweb.ru.
ns1.timeweb.ru.
```

вторая некорректность — в выводе a-записи от этих же серверов:

```
$ for s in dns{1,2}.yandex.net ns{1,2}.timeweb.ru ns{3,4}.timeweb.org; do echo "опрашиваем: $s"; dig +short @$s a ваше-имя; done
опрашиваем: dns1.yandex.net
опрашиваем: dns2.yandex.net
опрашиваем: ns1.timeweb.ru
5.23.50.118
опрашиваем: ns2.timeweb.ru
5.23.50.118
опрашиваем: ns3.timeweb.org
5.23.50.118
опрашиваем: ns4.timeweb.org
5.23.50.118
```

при дальнейших опросах, вероятно, выплывёт ещё двадцать три вагона несогласованностей.

вы либо согласуйте информацию между серверами имён, либо уберите из описания те серверы, которые показывают некорректную информацию (в вашем случае это, вероятно, яндексовские серверы).